# How to remove grainy details from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

I have used `adapthisteq` to improve the visibility of the foreground objects. However, this seems to have created grainy noisy details. How can I remove these grainy details from the image? I have tried Gaussian blurring through `imgaussfilt` and while it does remove some of the grainy details, the shape of the cells in the image become less defined. The second image shows the binary image of the first image.

[image: <code>adapthisteq</code>]
[image: <code>im2bw</code>]

Comment: I'd go for total variation image denoising, but be aware that your images are pretty hard to start with, you won't find a perfect library solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter that takes into consideration the edge information like bilateral filter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter
The bilateral filter doesn't only weighs the value according to the distance in pixels (like a regular Gaussian blurring) but also according to the distance in color between the pixels.

[image]
taken from: http://www.slideshare.net/yuhuang/fast-edge-preservingaware-high-dimensional-filters-for-image-video-processing

An Matlab implementation you can find here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12191-bilateral-filtering

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13228481)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you think i need to add something else?