# bilateral filtering in image processing

Tags: image, image-processing, filter, edge-detection, smoothing

Can anyone explain me how can I use  the equation of bilateral filter in an image ,each coefficient in equation how can use it on an array and how the filter leave the edge without smoothing ? can anyone help me, please?and why(Ip - Iq) multiply in Iq [image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768256/how-to-remove-grainy-details-from-an-image/38768984#38768984

Comment: thanks a lot , but I'm yet I can not understand the benefit of normalization and (Iq) in the last of the equation ? can u help?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani  ,pardon,can you answer my question

Comment: Iq is the pixel value of pixel q from the set of pixels S(which usually S just means the 8 negbrhood of a pixel)

Comment: The normalization is to make sure that the outcome of the pixel value will be proportional to the pixel values in the image.

Comment: In general you can think about that in the following way: Gmus and Gmur are weights that weigh the influence of pixel q on the calculation of the value of pixel p. You need to normalize the weights so they will sum up to 1 and because of that you use Wp.

Comment: thanks a lot ,if the (p-q) the distance between pixels and (Ip-Iq)the different in intensity between these pixels ,so how the filter preserving edge ,I'm sorry but I can not understand

Comment: why  was the use of this( Iq) why not this(Ip ) in the last of the equation                 I'm sorry for bothering you

Comment: For your first question if the distance in intensity is big we can assume that the two pixels are on different sides of an edge so the weight pixel iq will get is a low weight.

Comment: For the second question. The purpose of the filter is to assign a new value to pixel Ip based on its neigbrhood. that means that the new value of ip will be a function of its neigbhors the iq's.

Answer (score 3):

The filter computes a weighted sum of the pixel intensities. A normalization factor is always required in a weighted average, so that a constant signal keeps the same value.

The space factor makes sure that the filter value is influenced by nearby pixels only, with a smooth decrease of the weighting. The range factor makes sure that the filter value is influenced by pixels with close gray value only, with a smooth decrease of the weighting.

The idea behind this filter is to average the pixels belonging to the same homogeneous region as the center pixel, as if performing a local segmentation. The average performs smoothing/noise reduction, while restricting to the same region avoids spoling the edges by mixing with pixels of a very different intensity.